# How to sort by by existing state in a list

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch to build an application that show a list of books.
Each book can be marked as favorite. The page will show the favorited books on the top of the result list of the current user.

Here are some objects

```
public class User {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  //getters/setters
}
```

**Document**

```
public class Book
{
   private String name;
   private List<User> favoriteOfUsers;
   //getters/setters
}
```

I want to search the list and order them to get the favorited Books of the current user on the top of the result list.
Please tell me how could build a solution for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the sorting option from Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html

Assuming that the Users who favourited a book is stored as a nested list within the Book document, you're probably looking to use the `nested_filter` option in Elasticsearch's `sort`:

```
"sort" : [
   {
      "book" : {
         "mode" :  "avg",
         "order" : "asc",
         "nested_path" : "favouriteOfUsers",
         "nested_filter" : {
            "term" : { "favouriteOfUsers.id" : 1234 }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Function scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html). Assuming your document is of type:

```
  {
        "_index": "book",
        "_type": "book",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "name": "book1",
           "favoriteOfUsers": [
              {
                 "id": 1,
                // other properties of user

              },
              {
                 "id": 2,
               // other properties of user
              },
              {
                 "id": 3,
                 // other properties of user
              }
           ]
        }
     }
```

You can use following query

```
POST book/book/_search
{

"query": {
  "function_score": {
     "query": {
        "match_all": {}
     },
     "functions": [
        {
           "script_score": {
              "script": "if(_source.favoriteOfUsers*.id.contains(id)) {_score*10} else _score",
              "params": {
                 "id": 5
              }
           }
        }
     ]

     }
   } 
 }
```

If you are worried about security then you can use this [Running Groovy Scripts without Dynamic Scripting](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting)

Comment: I don't enable the inline script for security reason so that this is a good idea but I can't use it at all. Thanks :)